# I can't push nor publish my project to git + TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

I'm a bit new with **Git** and **TFS** from **Visual Studio**. In particular, for VS 2012.
I recently join in a project where the members will be using ***Git + TFS for VS 2012***. The first time I used Git from VS 2012 I followed all the steps mentioned in the following link:

http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/create-code-project-vs-git

As mention the first time when I was doing some test all worked OK, however now that I created a second project from my TFS account and create a solution from VS 2012 and then linked the solution with my Gir repository, I can't neither push or publish my local solution to the repository in Git.

I've recheck all the steps again and the only differences I have seen is the fact that the "Publish to [name of the Git project]" button is not longer available from my Visual Studio (***from the link above -> Publish your code into TFS section -> Connect your team project***)

If any of you guys have a clue of what's going on or a workaround, that will be very helpful

Regards!

Comment: Really, how are we supposed to help if you don't tell us what the exact problem is? Are you getting an error message? If so, which?

Comment: That's the problem. No error messages were showed. Now, from VS if I go to the branches option, in the unpublish branches there is an option: publish branch. If I click there now I get an error messages saying: libgit2 error with the net connection, there is an hex digit found in the connection. I re-check it and all seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am having the same problem as you, I didn't realize until now that in order to publish a local repository to TFS you must right click the TFS item and click connect, then right click the local repository and the publish button will be available.  This resolved the problem on my machine.